# How to change the completion/prediction hint color in PowerShell core in windows terminal?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11, powershell-core, windows-terminal

I have got the next problem, the color of the '**diff --staged**' on the picture is so gray. How to change the color?

**My OS:** Windows 11
**Environment:** Powershell Core & Windows Terminal

[image]

Comment: It's gray because it's a _suggestion_ - press they right-arrow key on your keyboard to accept it

Answer (score 4):

As [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes:

The gray part is a *suggested completion* of the command you're typing from your *command history*:

- To *accept* the suggestion (also known as an *inline prediction*), use the right-arrow key; for more information, including how to customize what key to use, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77016313/45375).
- To *change the color in which the suggestion is printed*, see the next section.

---

Use [`Set-PSReadLineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption) as follows, using `Cyan` in this example:

```bash
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ InlinePrediction = 'Cyan' }
```