# Using tab-completion in the shell for suggested command

Tags: powershell, command-line-arguments, tab-completion

*"PowerShell provides completions on input to provide hints, enable discovery, and speed up input entry. Command names, parameter names, argument values and file paths can all be completed by pressing the Tab key." [Using tab-completion in the shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/tab-completion?view=powershell-7.3)

I'm no stranger with using tab to complete a command, but I can't figure out how to use the hints.  For example, after typing **Connect-ExchangeOnline** it shows me greyed out text of an argument I used recently.

`Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName <User@Domain.com>`

However, pressing tab cycles through the list of arguments for the command.  I know I can use Ctrl + Space to see all the arguments, but how do I use the hinted argument it suggests?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsdoZ.png)

Google - I was expecting to find the answer, but I'm not quite sure how to describe this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grayed out suggestion is an ***inline prediction***, using your *command history* as the prediction source (other sources can be installed).

From [Using predictors in PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-predictors):

> Pressing [the] `RightArrow` key accepts an inline suggestion.

Specifically, it accepts the *whole* suggestion and places the cursor at the end of the line (without submitting it, so you can still edit it).

You can customize the key bindings via [`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler), by mapping a key (chord) to the following `PSReadLine` functions:<sup>[1]</sup>

- `AcceptSuggestion` ... exhibits the behavior described above.

  - `ForwardChar` does too, and that is the one that <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> is bound to by default.
- `AcceptNextSuggestionWord` ... only accepts the *next word* from the inline suggestion being offered.

  - `ForwardWord` does too, but it is only bound to a key chord by default on *Unix*-like platforms (<kbd>Alt+f</kbd>), not on *Windows* (where `AcceptNextSuggestionWord` isn't mapped either).
  - To define <kbd>Alt+f</kbd>, for instance, on Windows too, use the following:

    ```bash
    Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Alt+f -Function AcceptNextSuggestionWord
    ```

---

If you prefer to have **predictions presented in a *list***, so that you can select an entry using the up- an down-arrow keys (which invariably uses the *whole* prediction):

- Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to toggle between inline and list view, in-session (non-persistently).
- To default to list view in future session, place the following in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file:

  ```bash
  Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView
  ```

---

<sup>[1] See [about_PSReadLine_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline_functions) for a list of all functions, along with descriptions.</sup>